# domains read by melpa's JavaScript

Tags: package-repositories

I'm behind a firewall. What domains should I whitelist to be able to download packages from melpa? The JavaScript really obfuscates it.

Comment: Is `melpa.org` not enough? Do you mean by the MELPA website, or using MELPA from `package.el`?

Comment: Downloading packages with `package.el` doesn't execute any javascript. The only domains accessed are the archives you have configured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No domains other than `melpa.org` are necessary in order to browse and install packages via Emacs.

To browse and download packages via the web front-end, though, you'll also need to allow access to `cdnjs.cloudflare.com`, from which we load third-party javascript. This dependency may change in time.

Comment: Nevermind. I just found out I updated http://melpa-stable.org to http://melpa.stable.org, and not the correct http://stable.melpa.org. :P

Comment: Aha - that wouldn't help! :-)